# sorting numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, activex, sorting

I am reading some numbers from a local file and then trying to sort the numbers using Javascript.  Reading is done with the help of an ActiveXObject and the sorting with the help of javascript.

When I dont use ActiveX the sorting can be done but in the presence of Activex it doesn't work.  Are there any restrictions on using such functions in presence of ActiveX.  If someone can please tell me where the code needs to be altered I would be thankful.

Here is the code.

```
<html>
<script>
var oRequest;
var i;
var numbers=new Array();
var b= new Array();
var j
var k;
var temp;
var temp1;

if(document.all) {
  oRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
else {

  oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}


oRequest.open("GET", "file:///C:/Test.txt", true);
oRequest.send(null);


numbers= oRequest.responseText.split("\n");


for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<9;j++)
  {
    if(numbers[j]>numbers[j+1])
    {
      temp=numbers[j+1];
      numbers[j+1]=numbers[j];
      numbers[j]=temp;
    }
  }}

document.write(numbers);
document.write("<br>");
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens when you run the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: this is an issue of asynchronous code behaving asynchronously, not sorting numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `numbers` doesn't contain numbers, it contains strings. When you compare them they are compared as strings, not as numbers.

Parse the strings in the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) numbers[i] = parseInt(numbers[i], 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

AJAX (your XMLHTTP ActiveXObject), as its name states (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML), executes the request asynchronously, which means it schedules a GET request for your test.txt to be handled by another thread and continues with the execution of the rest of the javascript in the main thread.

You need to execute the rest of your javascript (the sorting) only AFTER the AJAX request has finished. To do that, you need to use the onreadystatechange event (info here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) and do the sorting only when readyState == 4 (4: request finished and response is ready) and status == 200 (200: "OK")

Answer (score 0):

Parse your strings to get numbers and then, use the `sort` method: http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

**EDIT:** And Shocker is right, of course.

Comment: Please don't reference W3Schools, use either ECMA-262 (online spec for [sort](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.11)) or MDN([sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) which are authoritative and informative.

Comment: Sorry, RobG. I forgot... But anyway, the method exists.